# Azure Search indexer data source

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have created an Index with an indexer and data source. But I don't remember the data source connection? I would like to know where the index is indexing the data from. 
I have tried the GET data source REST but the connection string is not there. 
How can I find out the source of the data?
It would be beneficial to know after it was created. Especially if your not the person that created the index in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Search doesn't return the connection string to avoid elevation of privilege disclosures, for example when a person with admin permissions to the database creates a datasource, then another person with just read permissions to Azure Search blade can view the full connection strings.

Perhaps a pragmatic middle ground is to return the connection string with most sensitive info such as password removed. Please open a suggestion on our [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Comment: I'm not interested in the password or credentials used. I'm after the location, server, blob storage, etc that the index is indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since connection strings are stored in an encrypted format they are not shown for security reasons.